# Multiplying rows of Sparse vectors in pyspark SQL DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having difficulties multiplying elements of columns in a SQL data frame.

```
sv1 = Vectors.sparse(3, [0, 2], [1.0, 3.0])
sv2 = Vectors.sparse(3, [0, 1], [2.0, 4.0])

def xByY(x,y):
  return np.multiply(x,y)

print(xByY(sv1, sv2))
```

The above works.

But the below doesn't.

```
xByY_udf = udf(xByY)

tempDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(sv1, sv2), (sv1, sv2)], ('v1', 'v2'))
tempDF.show()

print(tempDF.select(xByY_udf('v1', 'v2')).show())
```

Many thanks!

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your `udf` to return a `SparseVector`, we'll first need to modify the output of your function, and secondly set the output schema of the `udf` to `VectorUDT()`:

To declare a `SparseVector`, we need the **size** of the original array, and both the **indices** and the **values** of the **non-zero** elements. We can find these using `len()` and list comprehensions if the intermediate result of the multiplication is a `list`:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT

def xByY(x,y):
  res = np.multiply(x,y).tolist()
  vec_args =  len(res), [i for i,x in enumerate(res) if x != 0], [x for x in res if x != 0] 
  return Vectors.sparse(*vec_args)
```

Now we can declare our `udf` and test it:

```
xByY_udf = udf(xByY, VectorUDT())
tempDF.select(xByY_udf('v1', 'v2')).show()
+-------------+
| xByY(v1, v2)|
+-------------+
|(3,[0],[2.0])|
|(3,[0],[2.0])|
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! this (almost) works! How would I get a sparse vector back?

Comment: Totally brilliant, thank you. (The specification of the output schema of the UDF is something I always need to think carefully).